# How to pass parameters to the controller with the proper key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to get the store *id* on the controller side to delete the store.

Currently with this code my params on the controller side sends the `store.id(1)` as the value to the key format. I need to retrieve this by `store_id:` instead.

```
{..."controller"=>"home", "action"=>"delete_store", "format"=>"1"}
```

What I need:

```
{..."controller"=>"home", "action"=>"delete_store", "store_id"=>"1"}
```

HTML/ERB:

```
<h4>Your Stores:</h4>
  <% @my_stores.each do |store| %>
    <p><%= store.name %><%= link_to "X", delete_store_path(store.id), method: :delete %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
...
  def delete_store
    # With current code, I would have to do
    # current_user.stores.where(store_id: params[:format] )
    # But to make it proper I need this
    # current_user.stores.where(store_id: params[:store_id] )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it in the params with a `hidden_field_tag`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :store_id, store.id %>
```

This should allow you to do a lookup like:

```
params[:store_id]
```

Here is a link to the apidock for those wanting more info on `hidden_field_tag`.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag